# How to store bits to a huge char array for file input/output

Tags: c++, arrays, bit, shift

I want to store lots of information to a block by bits, and save it into a file.

To keep my file not so big, I want to use a small number of bits to save specified information instead of a int.

For example, I want to store Day, Hour, Minute to a file.

I only want 5 bit(day) + 5 bit(Hour) + 6 bit(Minute) = 16 bit of memory for data storage.

I cannot find a efficient way to store it in a block to put in a file.

There are some big problems in my concern:

1. the data length I want to store each time is not constant. It depends on the incoming information. So I cannot use a structure to store it.
2. there must not be any unused bit in my block, I searched for some topics that mentioned that if I store 30 bits in an int(4 byte variable), then the next 3 bit I save will automatically go into the next int. but I do not want it to happen!!
3. I know I can use shift right, shift left to put a number to a char, and put the char into a block, but it is inefficient.

I want a char array that I can continue putting specified bits into, and use write to put it into a file.

Comment: let me get this straight: you "can't find a efficient way to store it into a block to put it into a file" and these blocks are an exact 16 bits? Makes no sense to me...

Comment: What you propose would only work if the data fields are delimited with out-of-band methods like a data structure.  If your incoming data is free-form then bit-packed for storage, how will you ever know what it is when you read it back?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd just use the number of bits necessary to store the largest value you might ever need for any given piece of information. Then, Huffman encode the data as you write it (and obviously Huffman decode it as you read it). Most other approaches are likely to be less efficient, and many are likely to be more complex as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen such a library. So I'm afraid you'll have to write one yourself. It won't be difficult, anyway.

And about the efficiency. This kind of operations always need bits shifting and masking, because few CPUs support directly operating into bits, especially between two machine words. The only difference is you or your compiler does the translation.